# SharePoint Site Script throwning error

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-provision, site-design, site-script

I am planning to use `SharePoint Site Scripts to provision modern sites`. But, when I run command on PowerShell to add site script I am running to error.

[image]

I am facing the same issue, in other tenant as well. I checked this command with three developer tenants but all run into same issue. I also tried with `PnPPowerShell` but result into same problem.

**Edit**
When running the `Get-SPOSiteScript` command on any of those tenants, I am not getting anything but also it is not resulting into error. Following is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try running the Get-SPOSiteScript cmdlet. Check whether the cmdlet runs and returns with no errors. Refer to: How to run PowerShell cmdlets to create, retrieve, update, and remove site designs and site scripts to new and existing modern site collections. https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/declarative-customization/site-design-powershell.md

Comment: I am able to run `Get-SPOSiteScript` successfully. It doesn't return anything, but it also not result in any error. I updated the screenshot in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the string incorrectly.  Enclose it inside `@'` and `'@` as mentioned below:

```
$pnpTemplate = @'
{
  "$schema": "schema.json",
  "actions": [    
    {
      "verb": "createSPList",
      "listName": "Customer Tracking",
      "templateType": 100,
      "subactions": [
        {
          "verb": "SetDescription",
          "description": "List of Customers and Orders"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 1
}
'@
```

After that, you can run the SPO command as:

```
Add-SPOSiteScript -Title "Create Column RnD" -Content $pnpTemplate
```

Or the PnP command as :

```
Add-PnPSiteScript -Title "Create Column RnD" -Content $pnpTemplate
```

Comment: Hi @Gautam, that worked. But I was fetching the variable using `$pnpTemplate = Get-Content 'C:\ProvisioningTeamplate.json' -Raw` command. Do you know why this is not working? Also, in the first screenshot, it shows the variable value, when I compared that with your suggestion, I had the same output. So why that was not working?

Comment: not 100% sure but could be an issue with string formatting.  What i posted is the usage of `here-strings` which makes multi line reading of string easier. Check the links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30937024/862892), [here](http://tasteofpowershell.blogspot.in/2008/07/here-docs-in-powershell.html) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee692792(v=technet.10))

Comment: thanks. I got it, i'll check in my environment as well, if some settings are affecting it.